# Java String Manipulation Conditional replaceAll

Tags: java, conditional-statements, replaceall

I am reading in Strings from a file like...an example would be:

```
I JUMP UP HIGH IN THE AIR WITH SOUP TO GET TO YOU.
```

How would I do a conditional `replaceAll`, e.g. replace all `P` at end of word unless the word ends with `UP`.

This what I tried based on the example for `U` at the end of the word:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(!UP\\b)P\\b", "PS")
```

The above I would expect to change the string `s` to:

```
I JUMPS UP HIGH IN THE AIR WITH SOUP TO GET TO YOU.
```

Comment: This is a follow up question to the one found at... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835596/java-string-manipulation-replaceall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is pretty close: all you need is to check that the prior character is not a `U`, rather than `UP`, because `P` is already being matched:

```
(?<!U)P\b
```

This matches a single character `P` at the word boundary, unless it is preceded by a `U` character.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cD8rB7/1)

Comment: What if I don't want to change if it ends with OUP?

Comment: @Hedgebox Then you use `(?<!OU)` - i.e. `P` unless preceded by `OU`.

Comment: Tks. Is there a good tutorial on string manipulation with examples you can point me to?

Comment: @Hedgebox I keep [this tutorial handy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - it discusses regular expressions in great details.